# Check which member has the most connections

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a query, based on excel file.

I have a two columns table that shows transactions between friends.
I want to know which member has the most friends (it doesn't matter if he being paid or pays money).

Of course, two transations to or from the same person counts as one (I want to see how many friends, not how many times did he pay/got paid)
table

| paid | pays |
| --- | --- |
| 18 | 14 |
| 1 | 17 |
| 20 | 12 |
| 11 | 12 |
| 8 | 20 |
| 3 | 6 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 20 | 9 |
| 10 | 8 |
| 20 | 5 |
| 16 | 14 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 1 | 12 |
| 10 | 14 |
| 3 | 6 |
| 4 | 14 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 11 | 14 |

Comment: What are you asking here exactly? You don't actually ask anything. What is it you need help *with*? What have you tried to solve the question you haven't asked? Why didn't it work?

Comment: You say that the data is in an excel file, but you tag `sql` & `sql-server`. Are you looking for a `vba` Excel macro or have you linked the excel file to sql-server?

Comment: if it is in sql you want `select to friend, count(to) from (select to, from from transactions union all select from, to from transactions) group by to order by to`

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Hi,

first - thank you
second - It's in sql
third - I've tried, but the only thing I succeeded in, is to find the max for one cloumn (Like someone who pays and has the most number friends, or someone who get paid from the most number of friends)

Answer (score 0):

select max value from sub query like below example

```
select paid from (select paid,sum(pays) as `pays` from tbl) where pays=max(pays)
```